# Opening project file for a UHF RFID DevKit using Visual Studio

Tags: c#

I currently have a VS2010 installed on my Win7 Pro x64 computer. Then having downloaded the Source Code for the SDK of the device that i will modify, I opened it using VS2010 and after the conversion, it displayed the ff. error message:

> The project file 'C:\Users\Vostro 2420\Documents\AMS
>   Files\DL730&DL770_en_V3.5\DL730&DL770_RFID
>   DevKit\DL770\DL770WinCE\DL770WinCE\DL770WinCE.csproj' cannot be
>   opened. The project type is not supported by this installation.

Looking for some solutions here and some other websites, it seems that VS2010 does not support mobile development, so I installed XP Mode and installed Visual C#2005 there. But to no avail, still it doesn't work. It still gives the same "The project file cannot be loaded" error.

This is the content of the MS VS Solution file:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 9.00
# Visual Studio 2005
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "DL770WinCE",       "DL770WinCE\DL770WinCE.csproj", "{E07A0382-8B93-46A3-B389-C6D2C93CD4B8}"
EndProject
Global
        GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
            Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
            Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
        EndGlobalSection
        GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
            {E07A0382-8B93-46A3-B389-C6D2C93CD4B8}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
            {E07A0382-8B93-46A3-B389-C6D2C93CD4B8}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
            {E07A0382-8B93-46A3-B389-C6D2C93CD4B8}.Debug|Any CPU.Deploy.0 = Debug|Any       CPU
            {E07A0382-8B93-46A3-B389-C6D2C93CD4B8}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
            {E07A0382-8B93-46A3-B389-C6D2C93CD4B8}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
            {E07A0382-8B93-46A3-B389-C6D2C93CD4B8}.Release|Any CPU.Deploy.0 = Release|Any CPU
        EndGlobalSection
        GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
            HideSolutionNode = FALSE
        EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

Here is the content of the Visual C# Project file opened in Notepad:

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
        <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
        <ProductVersion>8.0.50727</ProductVersion>
        <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
        <ProjectGuid>{E07A0382-8B93-46A3-B389-C6D2C93CD4B8}</ProjectGuid>
        <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
        <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
        <RootNamespace>DL770WinCE</RootNamespace>
        <AssemblyName>DL770WinCE</AssemblyName>
        <ProjectTypeGuids>{4D628B5B-2FBC-4AA6-8C16-197242AEB884};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
        <PlatformFamilyName>WindowsCE</PlatformFamilyName>
        <PlatformID>E2BECB1F-8C8C-41ba-B736-9BE7D946A398</PlatformID>
        <OSVersion>5.0</OSVersion>
        <DeployDirSuffix>DL770WinCE</DeployDirSuffix>
        <TargetFrameworkVersion>v2.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
        <FormFactorID>
        </FormFactorID>
    </PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE;$(PlatformFamilyName)</DefineConstants>
    <NoStdLib>true</NoStdLib>
    <NoConfig>true</NoConfig>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <GenerateSerializationAssemblies>Off</GenerateSerializationAssemblies>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;$(PlatformFamilyName)</DefineConstants>
    <NoStdLib>true</NoStdLib>
    <NoConfig>true</NoConfig>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <GenerateSerializationAssemblies>Off</GenerateSerializationAssemblies>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="mscorlib" />
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
    <Reference Include="System.Windows.Forms" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Form1.cs">
        <SubType>Form</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Form1.Designer.cs">
        <DependentUpon>Form1.cs</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Program.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Form1.resx">
        <SubType>Designer</SubType>
        <DependentUpon>Form1.cs</DependentUpon>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Properties\Resources.resx">
        <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
        <LastGenOutput>Resources.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
        <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </EmbeddedResource>
    <Compile Include="Properties\Resources.Designer.cs">
        <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
        <DependentUpon>Resources.resx</DependentUpon>
        <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="RWDev.cs" />
</ItemGroup>
<Import Condition="'$(TargetFrameworkVersion)' == 'v1.0'" Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CompactFramework.CSharp.v1.targets" />
<Import Condition="'$(TargetFrameworkVersion)' == 'v2.0'" Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CompactFramework.CSharp.targets" />
<ProjectExtensions>
    <VisualStudio>
        <FlavorProperties GUID="{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}">
            <HostingProcess disable="1" />
        </FlavorProperties>
    </VisualStudio>
</ProjectExtensions>
<!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. 
        Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
    <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    </Target>
    <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    </Target>
-->
</Project>
```

Thanks in advance for helping. :D

Comment: looks like there are not many codes, have you try create a dummy project under 2005, then add in those cs/file one by one?
then compare the solution/proj you created with the original, and play around with the differences.

Comment: not yet, i'll give it a try...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon opening the solution file with notepad,
It seems that the codes were created with VS2005...

so I installed VS2005 Professional

App Development for Portable Device is only supported in Pro Versions
of Visual Studio...but in VS2010, some info on the internet
says that it doesn't support development for Mobile Devices anymore...

=)